# After uncheking checkbox with jquery it requires double click to be checked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap switch which shows (removes class hidden)  and hides (adds class hidden) checkbox.

Everytime bootstrap switch changes it unchecks the checkbox.

However, next time the checkbox is shown, it requires double click to be checked again.

```
$('#@Html.IdFor(p => p.ReassignRequestsCompany)').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function () {
    var state = $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state');
    $('.notifyNewCompanyAssigneeByEmail').find('.form-control').attr("data-checkbox", ""); // here I am uncheking the checkbox2
    $('.notifyNewCompanyAssigneeByEmail').removeClass('hidden'); // shows it here
    if (!state) {
        $('.notifyNewCompanyAssigneeByEmail').addClass('hidden'); // hides it here 
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add your html too

Comment: It's hard to debug something like this without some related html to go by.  However, my first guess is that your `$('.notifyNewCompanyAssigneeByEmail')` selector is to global and is changing more elements that it should be, rather than changing just the elements related to the particular switch that changed.